# Configure app.yaml in GAE to allow selection of scripts through URL

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created an app in Google App Engine and it's working pretty well in a conventional browser.  The main script is called example.py (because I have been hacking off an example and I never changed it).  It calls a html file and passes in variables as you would expect.

Now I want to develop a new version that's more suitable for mobile devices.  To do this, I wrote a new python script called example_mobile.py.  It's similar to example.py except that it calls a different html file with a different stylesheet.  Inelegant I know but I thought it would be easy to implement through the app.yaml file.

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
application: (my application id string)
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /mobile/.*
  script: example_mobile.py

- url: /.*
  script: example.py
```

www.(my domain name).com pulls up the output from example.py no problem.  I was hoping that www.(my domain name).com/mobile would pull up the output from example_mobile.py but it didn't work.  Also tried www.mobile.(my domain name).com but no luck.  Tried leaving off the /.* at the end of /mobile but that didn't help either. I switched example_mobile.py and example.py to check that it wasn't the python and I got the expected result so there's definitely something wrong with how I'm formatting and using the app.yaml file.  Can't seem to find a similar use case in the GAE docs so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dessie

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the `/mobile/.*` route you should visit `www.(my domain name).com/mobile/`

One simple suggestion is to have a single `example.py` matched by `/.*`  leaving the routing part to the WSGIApplication class.

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/mobile', example.MobileHandler),
                                     ( '/', example.MainHandler)],
                                     debug=True)
```

One rule of thumb here is that on `app.yaml` you should have different routes for different applications or different components.

Is `mobile` a different application/components or just the same application with a different theme and some lighter features?

Comment: your advice worked great. I agree that the /mobile/ route should have been activated by www.(my domain name).com/mobile but it wasn't. Your suggestion of adding a handler to the WSGIApplication class worked perfectly though.

Comment: @Dessie It didn't match because your regex for the mobile site specifies a trailing `/`, which you didn't supply.